# How to paste a paragraph word by word to excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I need to copy a paragraph and paste it in an Excel spreadsheet in a way that after pasting it each word of the paragraph is being placed in a separate row of the Excel sheet (and in the same column). Like this:

The paragraph:

> Microsoft Excel is a spreadsheet application developed by Microsoft for Microsoft Windows and Mac OS. It features calculation, graphing tools, pivot tables, and a macro programming language called Visual Basic for Applications.

and the Excel sheet after pasting the paragraph:

```
Microsoft
Excel
is
a
spreadsheet
application
developed
by
Microsoft
for 
.
.
.
```

Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Word, do a search/replace, replacing all spaces with paragraph breaks (^p). Select all the text and then copy/paste it into Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Copy paragraph to a text file and save. Go to Data->From Text (on left of ribbon), find file you just saved, then select "Delimited" and next.  On the next screen select space as delimiter.  This should put it all into one row.  Then copy the data in the row (not the entire row itself), right click on some empty cell in the sheet which will be your first cell and select "paste special"->"transpose".  This will put it into a column.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the default paste, right-click in Excel, in the cell where you want the paragraph to be placed, and select *Paste Special.*

A context box will inquire how you want the original information to be pasted. Select **Text**.